# Ubuntu 14.04 Exim 4.82 how to make tls_sni variable expanded in tls_certifcate?

Tags: 14.04, mail-server, tls, exim

I can't figure out how to make exim 4.82 recognise variable `${tls_sni}` in tls_certificate section.

I'm trying to make exim use per-domain certificates, but I'm getting an error

```
expansion of tls_certificate failed: unknown variable in "${tls_sni}"
```

Here is a part of my conf file

```
tls_certificate = ${if exists{CONFDIR/ssl/cert.${tls_sni}}{CONFDIR/ssl/cert.${tls_sni}}{CONFDIR/ssl/exim.cert}}
tls_privatekey = ${if exists{CONFDIR/ssl/key.${tls_sni}}{CONFDIR/ssl/key.${tls_sni}}{CONFDIR/ssl/exim.key}}
```

Section `log_selector +tls_sni` is logging incoming SNI values during tls/ssl session.

I have also tried to use variable `${tls_in_sni}` with the same result.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Apparently there's [a bug report](https://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499) on this issue, which states that the issue is resolved in version 4.83.

Comment: Was this problem fixed? Would someone mind sharing a working conf that allows me to dynamically match multiple ssl certs to exim4 virtual mail domains?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems there is a bug in Exim 4.82 compiled against GnuTLS:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.exim.devel/7292